# Why is a JAX-RS webapp not running properly with CXF 2.6.14 under WSO2 Application Server?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, cxf

I'm having a simple JPA-JaxRs webapp. It works fine for the first request. But from the second request it throws following error.

```
JAXBException occurred : name: `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.NamespaceMapper@fe9baf7`
```

My `jaxb` version is 2.2.7

If I use cxf 2.7.7 or higher version then this is not happening. Is this an existing bug? Is there any work around rather updating the cxf version
I'm testing this on WSO2-AS

I have tried samething on TomEE 1.7.2. There it works fine. They are also using CXF 2.6.16.

Comment: I would say that you should check with latest version and upgrade to it.

Comment: I agree with you. But in Tomee 1.7.2 they are using 2.6.16. But it works fine there. what could be the possible reason

Comment: Well that should be included in question. Can't say about the reason as I am limited with resources right now.